# Android. How to send mail without User participation?

Tags: android, email

is there any possibility to send mail from phone to phone's email account without any User participation?

I have found Intent for this, but User has to press button to complete operation.

Possibly there are some approaches to solve this.

Thanks.

Comment: [This post](http://nilvec.com/sending-email-without-user-interaction-in-android/) presents one solution. It uses javax.mail to send mails in the background.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I will supose the user knows the other phone's email and it knows how to add it to the program. The best way I think for doing this would be either to use a task app, that would need the user to configure it or use a flashable zip to install a script and run it with a crontab.

If you have Busybox in your phone, you can access `crontab` and `sendmail`. The idea is to write a little shell script with `sendmail` and make it run in the schedule you want thanks to `crontab`. That way you would be able to send emails without user confirmation or without the user having to push or do anything at all.

Also you can find several low level functions inside an Android terminal that could help you send the mail regarding some triggers. For example, you can use `dumpsys battery` to check on battery stats, so you can for example make a script that would check that and if battery is below a certain threshold, send a mail to warn the other phone.